# C++ Attaching Visual Studio debugger from command line

Tags: c++, visual-studio, debugging

is there any way to attach visual studio debugger to a C++ program by command line. I know I could use 'Debug/Attach To Process' but it dosent't help me in this case, since I have lots of process launched by the main process.

Answer (score 2):

From [Attach to running processes with the Visual Studio debugger](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/visualstudio-docs/blob/master/docs/debugger/attach-to-running-processes-with-the-visual-studio-debugger.md)

If neither of those workarounds is possible, a third option is to attach to the process by running `vsjitdebugger.exe -p <ProcessId>` from the Windows command line.